# How can I get strcasecmp to compare strings without being case sensitive

Tags: c, cs50

I am working on a cs50 online course in the C language and I have a project which is to write a function that will load a dictionary(database of words) into the memory, effectively hash it into a hash table and then compare words in the given text to check spelling, it must compare without case sensitivity.

I with this overview done the main problem I am having is getting my case-sensitivity down, thus I am unsure how I am going wrong with the strcasecmp function below. I am aware of memory leaks, however will sort them out later.

Below is the code in C:

```
    
    //for the universal hash function
    #define BASE 256
    
    // Represents a node in a hash table
    typedef struct node
    {
        char word[LENGTH + 1];
        struct node *next;
    }
    node;
    
    // Number of buckets in hash table
    const unsigned int N = 676;
    
    // Hash table
    node *table[N];
    int word_count = 0;
    
    // Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
    //Require a search funtion
    bool check(const char *word)
    {
        int hashIndex = hash(word);
        for (node *tmp = table[hashIndex]; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next)
        {
            
            if (strcasecmp(word, tmp->word) == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    // Hashes word to a number
    // the dividing hash function is one I cited from the yale.edu page http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/pinewiki/C(2f)HashTables.html having worked with.
    unsigned int hash(const char *word)
    {
        unsigned long m = 11;
        unsigned long h;
        unsigned const char *us;
        //ensure element value is >= 0 
        us = (unsigned const char *) word;
      
        h = 0;
        while(*us != '\0') 
        {
            h = (h * BASE + *us) % m;
            us++;
        } 
        return (h % N);
    }
```

When using the check50 function provided by CS50 to check this i get:

```
> :( spell-checking is case-insensitive expected "MISSPELLED WOR...",
> not "MISSPELLED WOR..." Log running ./speller case/dict case/text...
> checking for output "MISSPELLED WORDS\n\n\nWORDS MISSPELLED: 0\nWORDS
> IN DICTIONARY: 1\nWORDS IN TEXT: 8\n"...
> 
> Expected Output: MISSPELLED WORDS
> 
> 
> WORDS MISSPELLED:     0 WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  1 WORDS IN TEXT:       
> 8 Actual Output: MISSPELLED WORDS
> 
> foO fOo Foo fOO FoO FOo FOO
> 
> WORDS MISSPELLED:     7 WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  1 WORDS IN TEXT:       
> 8
> 
> :( handles most basic words properly expected "MISSPELLED WOR...", not
> "MISSPELLED WOR..." Log running ./speller basic/dict basic/text...
> checking for output "MISSPELLED WORDS\n\n\nWORDS MISSPELLED: 0\nWORDS
> IN DICTIONARY: 8\nWORDS IN TEXT: 9\n"...
> 
> Expected Output: MISSPELLED WORDS
> 
> 
> WORDS MISSPELLED:     0 WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  8 WORDS IN TEXT:       
> 9 Actual Output: MISSPELLED WORDS
> 
> The
> 
> WORDS MISSPELLED:     1 WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  8 WORDS IN TEXT:       
> 9
```

The main question is: How can I get this to compare two strings without case sensitivity?

Comment: The `unload` function only frees the first entry in each list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `if (strcasecmp(word, tmp->word) == 0)` is not the only place that word case is significant. What about `hash`? It needs to take letter case into account also, as 'A' and 'a', for example,  will hash to different values.

Comment: thanks i didn't take that into consideration, however would it be simpler to utilize the likes of tolower() to change anything entering the hash function to a standard case, thus eliminating the problem or is that a bad idea?

Comment: one other question I have solved all problems except one. with the new check implementation.                     char low[LENGTH + 1];
    
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(word); i <= (n + 1); i++)
    {
        low[i] = tolower(word[i]);
    }
     I am receiving  a valgrind problem of   "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)" pointing to the line low[i] = tolower(word[i]

Comment: what exactly s this indicating?

Comment: `low` not properly null terminated